# “Build a Product Landing Page” (FreeCodeCamp) -Error "When I click a .nav-link button in the nav element"

Tags: html, css

Good day!

I am doing a page programming task, and for a long time I cannot solve the "№5 “When I click a .nav-link button in the nav element, I am taken to the corresponding section of the landing page.” error. Please tell me what could be the problem?

link project: https://codepen.io/vjusmamh-the-lessful/pen/abwzVeG

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="./style.css" rel ="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <a name = "start">
    <header id="header">
        </a> <img id ="header-img" src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/product-landing-page-logo.png">
        <nav id="nav-bar">
            <a  class="nav-link" href="#Features">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#How it works " >How it works</a>
            <a  class="nav-link" href="#Pricing ">Pricing</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
</a>
    <main>
        
        <div id = "contact-block">
            <form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" method="get">
            <label for="email" id="email-label"> Handcrafted, home-made masterpieces</br></label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email"></input>
            <div id="button-container">
              <input type="submit" id="submit" value="GET STARTED"></input>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
    


        <a name = "Features">
    <div id = "info-block">
        <ul id = "info-list">
            <li id = "info-li"><p><strong>Premium Materials</strong> </br>
                Our trombones use the shiniest brass which is sourced locally. This will increase the longevity of your purchase.</p></li>
            <li id = "info-li"> <p><strong>Fast Shipping</strong> </br>
                We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p></li></li>
            <li id = "info-li">Quality Assurance</strong> </br>
                For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or faults and we will check and test the pitch of your instrument.</p></li> </li>
            
            </ul>
    </div>
    </a>

    <a name = "How it works">
    <div id="video-id">
        <video id="video">
            <source src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/y8Yv4pnO7qc" >
        </video>
    </div>
</a>
 <a name = "Pricing">
    <div id = "columns-block">
        <div id="col">
            <div id="header-col">TENOR TROMBONE</div>
            <div id="h2-col"><p>$600</p></div>
            <div id="col-text"><p>Lorem ipsum. </br>
                Lorem ipsum.</br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor.</br>
                Lorem ipsum.</br></p></div>
                <div id="col-button">
                    <form id="button-form">
                        <input id = "button" type="button" value="SELECT">
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="col">
            <div id="header-col">BASS TROMBONE</div>
            <div id="h2-col"><p>$900</p></div>
            <div id="col-text"> <p>Lorem ipsum.</br>
                Lorem ipsum.</br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor.</br>
                Lorem ipsum.</p></div>
                <div id="col-button">
                    <form id="button-form">
                        <input id = "button" type="button" value="SELECT">
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="col">
            <div id="header-col">VALVE TROMBONE</div>
            <div id="h2-col"><p>$1200</p></div>
            <div id="col-text"><p>Plays similar to a Trumpet</br>
                Great for Jazz Bands</br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor.</br>
                Lorem ipsum.</p></div>
                <div id="col-button">
                    <form id="button-form">
                        <input id = "button" type="button" value="SELECT">
                    </form>
                </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</a>
    <footer id="footer">
        <nav id="nav-bar">
            <a href ="#start" class ="nav-link">Privacy</a>
            <a href ="#start" class ="nav-link">Terms</a>
            <a href ="#start" class ="nav-link">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </footer>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

Your browser information:

User Agent is: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36

Challenge: Build a Product Landing Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have:

```
<a name = "Features">
```

Change to:

```
<a name = "Features" id="Features">
```

You must do this for all of the anchors in the page.

After a second look I see that you are wrapping the entire section in the `<a></a>` tag. Typically you would only wrap the location title like this:

```
    <a name = "Features" id="Features">Features</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried to change the code, but the problem is still the same: (Maybe I’m tired, but I still don’t understand how to solve the problem.

Comment: @Nikita remove the blank space before the closing quote: `href="#How it works " >How it works</a>`. Same for Pricing.

Comment: I did as you said. Moving from navigation box to text works. But "Select Test Suite" from "FreeCodeCamp" shows all the same error: " 5. When I click a .nav-link button in the nav element, I am taken to the corresponding section of the landing page.'
The .nav-link with href="#start" is not linked to a corresponding element on the page : expected null to not equal null
AssertionError: The .nav-link with href="#start" is not linked to a corresponding element on the page : expected null to not equal null" I don't even know what the problem might be. I've already tried everything.

Comment: Look at line 13 in the CodePen. You have a closing `</a>` tag that doesn't marry up to an opening `<a>` tag. Change `</a>` on line 13 to `<a id="start"></a>`. Now it passes. The error messages in red explain this.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I'm a beginner in layout, that's why I make such mistakes, thanks for the advice, this will improve my code.

Comment: @Nikita Glad it helped. Please accept the answer by clicking the green check mark.